# Insert a hyphen in the new "multiple-choice" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Recently a new tag called [multiplechoice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplechoice) was created — this should be [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), as it describes a property of the question rather than the puzzle itself. (It also cannot be used as the only tag on a question.)

I have removed it entirely.

Comment: Oh. well, that works too, I guess.

Comment: I disagree: a multiple-choice puzzle is a perfectly valid category of puzzle. I thought the creation of this tag was a very good idea, and went around adding it to several questions posted about multiple-choice puzzles. Surely it would be better to post a meta question asking for the community's opinion on whether this tag should be removed? Or at the very least expand your explanation of why you think it should be removed.

Comment: @randal'thor Why do you think that this tag isn't a meta tag, as described in the blog post linked?